# Magento 2 URL Not found after installation

Tags: ubuntu, magento, installation, magento2

I've installed Magento 2 on my ubuntu 20.04, I've tried to open up the landing page but it doesn't compile well and all the css is disturbed too. It says:

```
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

Please see the below image to get a clear idea about it.

What I've tried:

- Clearing out the cache using bin/magento cache:clean
- Compiling the static assets
- enabling developer mode.

Please guide how can i fix it. Thanks. Its new installation without any prior data.
[image]

Edit:
After running the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` commands
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

If you are facing theming issue after Installation in Magento 2. You can follow these steps :

Run this query:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

For local machine run this query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE core_config_data.path LIKE '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';
```

Remove all the files from pub and var directory:

```
sudo rm -rf var/di var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/cache/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/ pub/static/deployed_version.txt
```

Give Permission to var and pub directories of your project:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/* pub/*
```

Upgrade Setup:

```
sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Deploy content:

Answer (score 0):

did you run the setup:upgrade and di:compile commands

seems the generated files are not available

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Still same. I did restarted the apache server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some trouble with the .htaccess file? Copy this file from git with the current M2 version and paste it to your project dir

Comment: I switched from linux to windows and magento is working fine. Can you please guide me on some resources to create Magento Themes?

Comment: @psychodeveloper Magento devdocs has a complete manual about theme creating: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/theme-best-practice.html or maybe an alternative manual from mageplaza is fine for you - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your database in the table 'core_config_data' that the web/unsecure/base_url and the web/secure/base_url match the url of the site you're trying to reach.

Then just run:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento set:up

php bin/magento c:f

refresh the page and see if it fixes it.

Another thing i can think of is check your file permissions
You can find some info about this here: [File permissions for M2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the frontName in the env.php inside app/etc/env.php
else you can check the entry in the core_config table there the magento url is mention just copy and hit it on the browser